# Decode Cæsar Cypher by Checking all Keyspaces

Tags: python, python-2.x, caesar-cipher

This function produces a decoded string, `decoded`, for all keyspaces against a given cæsar cipher ciphertext. Punctuation is not changed and `string.upper()` is used to make working with `ord()` easier.

I am looking for a more Pythonic way to work with my `decoded` variable. I keep finding myself assigning empty strings or `None` or `0` to use as a placeholder and I think it looks ugly. I'd also like to know if there is a better way to avoid writing `c = ord(c)`.

```
def testCaesar(ciphertext):
    for testkey in range(0,25):
        decoded = ''   # <--- uglyness
        for c in ciphertext.upper():
            if not c.isalpha():
                decoded += c
                continue
            c = ord(c) # this is here to improve readability of line below. Is there a better way?
            decoded += chr(c + testkey if c + testkey < 90 else c - testkey)
        print('{0} : Rot{1} Caesar').format(decoded, str(testkey))
        checkMatch(decoded, testkey, 'Caesar')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest I see no problem with using `decoded = ''`. However I do have a good way to improve the readability of your character decoding. Replace this:

```
    c = ord(c) # this is here to improve readability of line below. Is there a better way?
    decoded += chr(c + testkey if c + testkey < 90 else c - testkey)
```

with this:

```
    decoded += decode(testkey, c)
```

Now all you need is a `decode` function, which can do the actual character decoding. You can give `decode` a good docstring and that'll make it a lot easier to follow what's happening, especially as you could remove the ternary there:

```
def decode(key, character):
    position = ord(character)
    if position + key < 90:
        position += key
    else:
        position -= key

    return chr(position)
```

Of course, one other thing you could add is your `isalpha` test directly in there by starting with:

```
    if not character.isalpha():
        return character
```

Now that would change your original loop to this:

```
decoded = ''
for c in ciphertext.upper():
    decoded += decode(testkey, c)
```

Well now we *can* remove your initial empty string. We can just use `str.join` with a generator expression. Generators are like for loops collapsed into a single expression, and you can make a simple one in this case:

```
decoded = ''.join(decode(testkey, c) for c in ciphertext.upper())
```

This makes a single string from each value that `decode` returns for every character in `ciphertext`. This would refactor your code like this:

```
def decode(key, character):
    if not character.isalpha():
        return character
    position = ord(character)
    if position + key < 90:
        position += key
    else:
        position -= key

    return chr(position)

def testCaesar(ciphertext):
    for testkey in range(0,25):
        decoded = ''.join(decode(testkey, c) for c in ciphertext.upper())
        print('{0} : Rot{1} Caesar').format(decoded, str(testkey))
        checkMatch(decoded, testkey, 'Caesar')
```

Comment: Using a generator looks a lot better to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `else` instead of `continue` to mark the 2 potential results of your test. You get something like :

```
def testCaesar(ciphertext):
    for testkey in range(0,25):
        decoded = ''   # <--- uglyness
        for c in ciphertext.upper():
            if not c.isalpha():
                decoded += c
            else:
                c = ord(c) # this is here to improve readability of line below. Is there a better way?
                decoded += chr(c + testkey if c + testkey < 90 else c - testkey)
        print('{0} : Rot{1} Caesar').format(decoded, str(testkey))
        checkMatch(decoded, testkey, 'Caesar')
```

Now, you've got some duplicated logic you could try to remove. You could use a new variable like :

```
def testCaesar(ciphertext):
    for testkey in range(0,25):
        decoded = ''   # <--- uglyness
        for c in ciphertext.upper():
            if not c.isalpha():
                decoded_c = c
            else:
                c = ord(c) # this is here to improve readability of line below. Is there a better way?
                decoded_c = chr(c + testkey if c + testkey < 90 else c - testkey)
            decoded += decoded_c
        print('{0} : Rot{1} Caesar').format(decoded, str(testkey))
        checkMatch(decoded, testkey, 'Caesar')
```

Or you could define a function for this :

```
def decode_char(c, key):
    if not c.isalpha():
        return c
    else:
        c = ord(c) # this is here to improve readability of line below. Is there a better way?
        return chr(c + testkey if c + testkey < 90 else c - testkey)


def testCaesar(ciphertext):
    for testkey in range(0,25):
        decoded = ''   # <--- uglyness
        for c in ciphertext.upper():
            decoded += decode_char(c, testkey)
        print('{0} : Rot{1} Caesar').format(decoded, str(testkey))
        checkMatch(decoded, testkey, 'Caesar')
```

Now, Python has a style guide called [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and it says :

> Do not rely on CPython's efficient implementation of in-place string
>   concatenation for statements in the form a += b or a = a + b . This
>   optimization is fragile even in CPython (it only works for some types)
>   and isn't present at all in implementations that don't use
>   refcounting. In performance sensitive parts of the library, the
>   ''.join() form should be used instead. This will ensure that
>   concatenation occurs in linear time across various implementations.

This can be easily done now :

```
decoded = ''.join(decode_char(c, testkey) for c in ciphertext.upper())
```

Also, a tiny optimisation could be to call `upper()` once and only once.

Answer (score 2):

## Format

There is one line that bothers me a lot:

```
print('{0} : Rot{1} Caesar').format(decoded, str(testkey))
```

First of, you don't need `str` when dealing with `format`. This is the whole point of using `format`: you don't have to deal with converting stuff into strings first, you let `format` handle it for you.

Second, the call is very weird. You usually call format directly on the string, not on enclosing parenthesis. This is even more confusing as `print` was changed from a keyword to a function in Python 3. So the meaning of this line is changed between Python 2 and Python 3.

In Python 2, `format` is applied on the string.

In Python 3, `format` is applied on the returned value of the `print` function. Meaning you try to call `None.format(...)` which raise an `AttributeError`.

Ideally, you should write this line as:

```
print('{0} : Rot{1} Caesar'.format(decoded, testkey))
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing these out, both late-night SNAFUs that I'm not experienced enough to have jump out at me.

Answer (score 1):

```
decoded = ''   # <--- ugliness
for c in ciphertext.upper():
    if not c.isalpha():
        decoded += c
        continue
    c = ord(c)  # Is there a better way?
    decoded += chr(c + testkey if c + testkey < 90 else c - testkey)
```

Yes, there are better ways. They come from functional programming.

Try to adhere to the idea of "one concept, one name" as much as possible. For example, on the penultimate line above, you use the name `c` to mean both "the ciphertext character" *and* "the `ord` of the ciphertext character". Don't do that. Instead, use a *new* name for the new concept "`ord` of the ciphertext character"; for example, `ord_c`.

```
    ord_c = ord(c)
    decoded += chr(ord_c + testkey if ord_c + testkey < 90 else ord_c - testkey)
```

In the above code, `ord_c = ord(c)` is basically a *definition* of what `ord_c` means in the code. You could go replace every instance of `ord_c` in the program with `ord(c)`, and the program would still work fine. This is a nice property for a program to have; it's known as [*referential transparency*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency). A perfect program won't have any places where you say "Hey, you know that variable `foo` from earlier? Well, now it means something totally different." If the variable *means* something different, you should give it a different *name*.

Next, *decompose* your program into functions. For example, take that messy expression you're trying to get rid of, and stick it in a function:

```
def rotate(c, key):
    ord_c = ord(c)
    if ord_c + key < 90:
        return chr(ord_c + key)
    else:
        return chr(ord_c - key)

decoded = ''   # <--- ugliness
for c in ciphertext.upper():
    if not c.isalpha():
        decoded += c
        continue
    decoded += rotate(c, testkey)  # less ugliness
```

(Incidentally, you probably meant `chr(ord_c + key - 26)`, not `chr(ord_c - key)`.)

Next, use *[structured programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming)* to get rid of the `goto`-style jumps in your code. Yes, `continue` and `break` count as jumps.

```
decoded = ''   # <--- ugliness
for c in ciphertext.upper():
    if c.isalpha():
        decoded += rotate(c, testkey)
    else:
        decoded += c
```

Finally, the code is clean enough to notice that what we're really doing here is transforming a string character-by-character: for each character in the input `ciphertext`, we produce a corresponding character in the output `decoded`. So we can use a [comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Comprehensions) to get the same result directly, with no intermediate state:

```
def decode(c, key):
    if not c.isalpha():
        return c
    elif ord(c) + key < 90:
        return chr(ord(c) + key)
    else:
        return chr(ord(c) - key)

decoded = ''.join(decode(c, testkey) for c in ciphertext.upper())
```